# Parsing a string line by line into arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, parsing

I'm quite a novice in Python but I need to do some parsing for a research project. I see it as the most difficult part now that I need to overcome to do the actual science. One of basic things I need is to convert a string with the data into NumPy lists. An example of the data:

```
CARBON
S   9
1         6.665000E+03           6.920000E-04
2         1.000000E+03           5.329000E-03
3         2.280000E+02           2.707700E-02
4         6.471000E+01           1.017180E-01
5         2.106000E+01           2.747400E-01
6         7.495000E+00           4.485640E-01
7         2.797000E+00           2.850740E-01
8         5.215000E-01           1.520400E-02
9         1.596000E-01          -3.191000E-03
S   9
1         6.665000E+03          -1.460000E-04
2         1.000000E+03          -1.154000E-03
3         2.280000E+02          -5.725000E-03
4         6.471000E+01          -2.331200E-02
5         2.106000E+01          -6.395500E-02
6         7.495000E+00          -1.499810E-01
7         2.797000E+00          -1.272620E-01
8         5.215000E-01           5.445290E-01
9         1.596000E-01           5.804960E-01
S   1
1         1.596000E-01           1.000000E+00
P   4
1         9.439000E+00           3.810900E-02
2         2.002000E+00           2.094800E-01
3         5.456000E-01           5.085570E-01
4         1.517000E-01           4.688420E-01
P   1
1         1.517000E-01           1.000000E+00
D   1
1         5.500000E-01           1.0000000
```

This needs to be read for N arbitrary atoms, so can be called in a for loop and the first line may be omitted. The parser has to read the letter (S, L, P, D, F), the number Nc on the right from it, start a for loop for Nc lines and copy the 2nd and 3rd columns into NumPy arrays that may belong to some class. That would form a contracted Gaussian-type orbital and I would do some math with it. If the letter is L, I would need to use a different class because a 4th column would appear. If the Nc value == 1 it would be just one line to read and another class. After the reading of all the N strings is done, the data should look something like this:

```
 C         

   1   S    1    6665.000000    0.363803 (  0.000692) 
   1   S    2    1000.000000    0.675392 (  0.005329) 
   1   S    3     228.000000    1.132301 (  0.027077) 
   1   S    4      64.710000    1.654004 (  0.101718) 
   1   S    5      21.060000    1.924978 (  0.274740) 
   1   S    6       7.495000    1.448149 (  0.448564) 
   1   S    7       2.797000    0.439427 (  0.285074) 
   1   S    8       0.521500    0.006650 (  0.015204) 
   1   S    9       0.159600   -0.000574 ( -0.003191) 

   2   S   10    6665.000000   -0.076756 ( -0.000146) 
   2   S   11    1000.000000   -0.146257 ( -0.001154) 
   2   S   12     228.000000   -0.239407 ( -0.005725) 
   2   S   13      64.710000   -0.379069 ( -0.023312) 
   2   S   14      21.060000   -0.448104 ( -0.063955) 
   2   S   15       7.495000   -0.484201 ( -0.149981) 
   2   S   16       2.797000   -0.196168 ( -0.127262) 
   2   S   17       0.521500    0.238162 (  0.544529) 
   2   S   18       0.159600    0.104468 (  0.580496) 

   3   S   19       0.159600    0.179964 (  1.000000) 

   4   P   20       9.439000    0.898722 (  0.038109) 
   4   P   21       2.002000    0.711071 (  0.209480) 
   4   P   22       0.545600    0.339917 (  0.508557) 
   4   P   23       0.151700    0.063270 (  0.468842) 

   5   P   24       0.151700    0.134950 (  1.000000) 

   6   D   25       0.550000    0.578155 (  1.000000) 

 C         

   7   S   26    6665.000000    0.363803 (  0.000692) 
   7   S   27    1000.000000    0.675392 (  0.005329) 
   7   S   28     228.000000    1.132301 (  0.027077) 
   7   S   29      64.710000    1.654004 (  0.101718) 
   7   S   30      21.060000    1.924978 (  0.274740) 
   7   S   31       7.495000    1.448149 (  0.448564) 
   7   S   32       2.797000    0.439427 (  0.285074) 
   7   S   33       0.521500    0.006650 (  0.015204) 
   7   S   34       0.159600   -0.000574 ( -0.003191) 

   8   S   35    6665.000000   -0.076756 ( -0.000146) 
   8   S   36    1000.000000   -0.146257 ( -0.001154) 
   8   S   37     228.000000   -0.239407 ( -0.005725) 
   8   S   38      64.710000   -0.379069 ( -0.023312) 
   8   S   39      21.060000   -0.448104 ( -0.063955) 
   8   S   40       7.495000   -0.484201 ( -0.149981) 
   8   S   41       2.797000   -0.196168 ( -0.127262) 
   8   S   42       0.521500    0.238162 (  0.544529) 
   8   S   43       0.159600    0.104468 (  0.580496) 

   9   S   44       0.159600    0.179964 (  1.000000) 

  10   P   45       9.439000    0.898722 (  0.038109) 
  10   P   46       2.002000    0.711071 (  0.209480) 
  10   P   47       0.545600    0.339917 (  0.508557) 
  10   P   48       0.151700    0.063270 (  0.468842) 

  11   P   49       0.151700    0.134950 (  1.000000) 

  12   D   50       0.550000    0.578155 (  1.000000)
```

This is an example of a full basis set of a molecule made of individual atomic basis sets. The first column is the basis function number, the second is the basis function type (S, L, P, D, F, etc), the third is the primitive basis function number and the next two are those read by the parser. How would one recommend me to do it, so I get the ordered data like above? And how exactly can strings be read into arrays line by line? Python's functionality is overwhelming. I tried to use Pandas to convert a string into some array to "filter" it but it couldn't work for me.

Comment: What do you want to end up with?  A pandas DataFrame?  Or just a list of rows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you a start.  I made up the column names; you should provide correct ones.  This will handle multiple molecules in a single file, but it will just concatenate them all into one dataframe.  I would guess (based on no evidence) that you probably want one dataframe per molecule.

```
import pandas as pd

rows = []
for line in open('x.txt'):
    parts = line.strip().split()
    if len(parts) == 1:
        print(parts[0])
        counter1 = 0
        counter2 = 0
    elif len(parts) == 2:
        counter1 += 1
        shell = (counter1, parts[0])
    else:
        counter2 += 1
        rows.append( shell + (counter2, float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])) )

df = pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=['basisnum','basistype','primitive','energy','delta'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
CARBON
    basisnum basistype  primitive     energy     delta
0          1         S          1  6665.0000  0.000692
1          1         S          2  1000.0000  0.005329
2          1         S          3   228.0000  0.027077
3          1         S          4    64.7100  0.101718
4          1         S          5    21.0600  0.274740
5          1         S          6     7.4950  0.448564
6          1         S          7     2.7970  0.285074
7          1         S          8     0.5215  0.015204
8          1         S          9     0.1596 -0.003191
9          2         S         10  6665.0000 -0.000146
10         2         S         11  1000.0000 -0.001154
11         2         S         12   228.0000 -0.005725
12         2         S         13    64.7100 -0.023312
13         2         S         14    21.0600 -0.063955
14         2         S         15     7.4950 -0.149981
15         2         S         16     2.7970 -0.127262
16         2         S         17     0.5215  0.544529
17         2         S         18     0.1596  0.580496
18         3         S         19     0.1596  1.000000
19         4         P         20     9.4390  0.038109
20         4         P         21     2.0020  0.209480
21         4         P         22     0.5456  0.508557
22         4         P         23     0.1517  0.468842
23         5         P         24     0.1517  1.000000
24         6         D         25     0.5500  1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very close to what I needed. I also need to group those parts of data that come, for example, after S  9 lines because they represent a single basis function as a sum of primitive ones. There's some math to do with it immediately so it requires writing a function which I'll do.

Question: this array of data, the full basis set, will be accessed a lot and may contain several thousands of lines. Is Pandas an optimal way of storing it, would NumPy make a change? Although I sincerely hate NumPy's indexing way.

Comment: Pandas may not be optimal, but it is convenient.  It uses numpy for the mathematics, and numpy is VERY efficient.  However, numpy doesn't handle mixed types like that very well, which is why pandas was invented.  Note that "grouping" just just an output consideration; it doesn't affect the storage in any way.  With thousands of lines, performance isn't going to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep posting here if having more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Tim Roberts**, I was able to write a piece of code for parsing basis sets. It's incomplete, another elif is needed to read SP/L basis functions but it works.

```
import basis_set_exchange as bse
import pandas as pd

basis = bse.get_basis('cc-pVDZ', fmt = 'gamess_us', elements = 'C', header = False)
basis = basis[5:-4]

print(basis, '\n')

buf = basis.split('\n')
buf.pop(2)

shellNumber = 0
shellType = ''
rows = []

for line in buf:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    if (len(parts) == 2):
        shellType = parts[0]
        shellNumber += 1
    elif (len(parts) == 3):
        rows.append((shellType, shellNumber, float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])))

df = pd.DataFrame( rows, columns = ['SHELL TYPE','SHELL NO','EXPONENT','CONTR COEF'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
CARBON
S   9
1         6.665000E+03           6.920000E-04
2         1.000000E+03           5.329000E-03
3         2.280000E+02           2.707700E-02
4         6.471000E+01           1.017180E-01
5         2.106000E+01           2.747400E-01
6         7.495000E+00           4.485640E-01
7         2.797000E+00           2.850740E-01
8         5.215000E-01           1.520400E-02
9         1.596000E-01          -3.191000E-03
S   9
1         6.665000E+03          -1.460000E-04
2         1.000000E+03          -1.154000E-03
3         2.280000E+02          -5.725000E-03
4         6.471000E+01          -2.331200E-02
5         2.106000E+01          -6.395500E-02
6         7.495000E+00          -1.499810E-01
7         2.797000E+00          -1.272620E-01
8         5.215000E-01           5.445290E-01
9         1.596000E-01           5.804960E-01
S   1
1         1.596000E-01           1.000000E+00
P   4
1         9.439000E+00           3.810900E-02
2         2.002000E+00           2.094800E-01
3         5.456000E-01           5.085570E-01
4         1.517000E-01           4.688420E-01
P   1
1         1.517000E-01           1.000000E+00
D   1
1         5.500000E-01           1.0000000

 

   SHELL TYPE  SHELL NO   EXPONENT  CONTR COEF
0           S         1  6665.0000    0.000692
1           S         1  1000.0000    0.005329
2           S         1   228.0000    0.027077
3           S         1    64.7100    0.101718
4           S         1    21.0600    0.274740
5           S         1     7.4950    0.448564
6           S         1     2.7970    0.285074
7           S         1     0.5215    0.015204
8           S         1     0.1596   -0.003191
9           S         2  6665.0000   -0.000146
10          S         2  1000.0000   -0.001154
11          S         2   228.0000   -0.005725
12          S         2    64.7100   -0.023312
13          S         2    21.0600   -0.063955
14          S         2     7.4950   -0.149981
15          S         2     2.7970   -0.127262
16          S         2     0.5215    0.544529
17          S         2     0.1596    0.580496
18          S         3     0.1596    1.000000
19          P         4     9.4390    0.038109
20          P         4     2.0020    0.209480
21          P         4     0.5456    0.508557
22          P         4     0.1517    0.468842
23          P         5     0.1517    1.000000
24          D         6     0.5500    1.000000
```

After reading the entire atomic basis set, the dataframe will have to be transformed into an actual basis set. After that, it can be used in a calculation.